# WebAudioAPI DynamicsCompressorNode: Peak output of a pulse is way more than input

Tags: javascript, signal-processing, web-audio-api

I'm still having some issues with making an ADSR envelope with the `DynamicsCompressorNode`.

Perhaps the only thing that is standing in my way is the fact that the compressor's attack seems to amplify the input pulse by a very large, but unknown factor.

Here's my set up:

I have a `ConstantSourceNode` that outputs a 1 as long as the note is held down, and 0 if it's not. This will be the gate input.

Now the gate input is fed to the input of the compressor, out of which I want to get an attack transient. The compressor is set like this:

```
  let THRESHOLD = -60;
  let KNEE = 3;
  let COMP_RATIO = 18;

  comp.threshold.value = THRESHOLD;
  comp.knee.value = KNEE;
  comp.ratio.value = COMP_RATIO;    
  comp.attack.value = 0;
  comp.release.value = 0;

  attackTime.connect(comp.attack);
```

Where `comp` is a DynamicsCompressorNode and `attackTime` is a ConstantSourceNode, which level is constantly at a sixth of the attack duration.

Here's the weird part: Everything works except for the fact that the peak output level of `comp` is somewhere around 50, whereas, the input gate has a peak level of only 1.

Do I have to find the weird gain coefficient by trial and error, or is there some reason behind this around-50-fold gain that will allow me to calculate and compensate this gain increase properly?

Edit: I found out that the random gain increase is proportional to the attack duration. I shall plot a graph and try to see how are the two related.